# Exposing application API and data to DLL

Tags: c++, dll, plugins

I have a dll plugin ,myDLL.cpp, which has the following code:

```
#include "myDLL.h"
#include "MainApp.h"
class A{
public:
   // NOTE: SomeType is defined in main application code.
   A(SomeType* data) : m_data{data}
   void MemberFunc(){
       // NOTE: do_something should access data in main application.
       m_data->do_something();
   }
private:
   SomeType* m_data;
};
// exported function
A* createInstance(SomeType* data){
   return new A(data);
}
```

In the main application I have:

```
stc::vector<int> IntArray;

class SomeType{
    SomeType(){
        IntArray.resize(1000);
    }
    void do_something(){
        // manipulate IntArray's contents.
        IntArray[rand() % IntArray.size()] = rand();
    }
};

typedef A*(_createInstance)(SomeType*);
void main(){
    // Load the Dll and get createInstance()
    _createInstance createInstance = LoadMyDLL();

    SomeType someType;
    A* a = createInstance(&someType);

    a->MemberFunc();

    // Free the instance of A and unload the DLL.
    UnloadMyDLL(a);
}
```

The dll code now can use the API of the main application, but it can't access the right data. When I put a break point at `m_data->do_something();` and enter the method call, then I see that `IntArray` is empty. What am I doing wrong and how do I solve the problem?

Comment: I tried your code, making a VS solution with the dll on one side and the app on the other.  I defined in my app a reference to the DLL, so I didn't have to use your `LoadMyDLL()`. It worked perfectly. THe only thing was that IntArray was not visible on the breakpoint:  only when I steped with F11 into doSomething() could I inspect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could succesfully run your example without experiencing your problem:

- I assumed that in your headers there are only the class definitions and not definition of its member functions
- So I buid a DLL project.  But it failed producing the dll because of the missing `do_something()` function.  Normal, because with your architecture it should be defined in the application not in the DLL ! I could solve the problem by making `do_something()` virtual.
- Then I build the application.  I first chose for simplicity and linked the application with the DLL (no loading issues).  Unfortunately it didn't find either `MemberFunc()` nor `createInstance()`.  I could solve this by exporting the DLL entry.
- FInally I updated the application, to have a dynamic load of the library.  For avoiding unnecessary hassle of having to find back `MemberFunc()`, I made it virtual as well.

In all the tests above, I had absolutely no problem.  `IntArray` was always correct.  In debug mode I could see it with the expected content, as soon as it entered the scope.

My conclusion, from these tests and looking at your snippet (expecially with doSomething not being virtual):  **your problem is probably** that  have defined `SomeType` class with functions and eventually `IntArray` in `Main.h`.

If this is the case, your DLL refers to its own copy of these elements and not as you think to those in main !  THis explains why you don't see the expected values !

Solution:

File **MainApp.h**:

```
class SomeType{
public:
    SomeType();
    virtual void do_something();
};
```

File **MyDLL.h**:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

class A {
public:
    A(SomeType* data); 
    virtual  void MemberFunc();  // access through vtable. No need to link
private:
    SomeType* m_data;
};
extern "C" {   // use unmangled name for easo of use of dynamic loaded DLL  
    MYDLL_API A*  createInstance(SomeType* data);
};
```

File **MyDLL.cpp**:

```
#define MYDLL_EXPORTS 
#include "MainApp.h"
#include "MyDLL.h"

A::A(SomeType* data) : m_data{ data } {}

void A::MemberFunc(){  m_data->do_something(); }

extern "C" {  
    MYDLL_API A*  cdecl createInstance(SomeType* data){ return new A(data); }
}
```

File **main.cpp**:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "MainApp.h"
#include "MyDLL.h"
using namespace std; 

vector<int> IntArray;

SomeType::SomeType(){
        IntArray.resize(1000); 
        IntArray[0] = 1; IntArray[1] = 101; IntArray[2] = 10101;
    }
void SomeType::do_something(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // read 
        cout << IntArray[i] << endl; 
    IntArray[3] = 2702;          // write
    }

int main(int ac, char**av) 
{
    HINSTANCE LoadMe = LoadLibrary(L"MyDLL.dll");
    if(LoadMe != 0) 
        cout << "DLL Library successfully loaded!\n";
    else throw exception("DLL library failed to load!\n");

    typedef A*(*_createInstance)(SomeType*);
    _createInstance fcreateInstance = (_createInstance) GetProcAddress(LoadMe, "createInstance");
    if (fcreateInstance) 
        cout << "DLL function found !\n";
    else throw exception("Function not found in DLL!\n");

    SomeType someType;
    A* a = fcreateInstance(&someType);
    a->MemberFunc();

    cin.get(); 
}
```